# Проблема с настройкой datepicker ui

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Проблема в том что я вывел datepicker, но при первом клике он выбирает сразу две даты, текущую и ту что была выбрана. Как убрать данную проблему, подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
jQuery('#date_range').datepicker({
   minDate: '+0',
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
   numberOfMonths: 3,
   range: 'multiple', // режим - выбор нескольких дат
   dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
   range_multiple_max: '25', // макимальное число выбираемых дат
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst, extensionRange) {
       // extensionRange - объект расширения
      jQuery('input[name=multipleDate]').val(extensionRange.datesText.join(','));
}
```

Comment: Что значит выбирает сразу две даты? По умолчанию просто текущая всегда подсвечивается..

Comment: Речь не в подсветке, а конкретно в выборе в добавлении. Как Вам удобнее. То есть к примеру сегодня 11.09.2017. Я в календаре нажимаю на 23.09.2017 и он мне в мой input type="text" вставляет две даты и 11.09.2017 и 23.09.2017. Хотя я выбрал только 23-е число, дальше все норм, добавляет те даты которые я выбираю, но при первом нажатии обязательно текущую дату добавляет.

Comment: Попробуйте принудительно поставить ему `defaultDate: null,`

Comment: Добавил, не помогло, к сожалению.

Comment: А что в вашем коде значит: range_multiple_max: '25', // макимальное число выбираемых дат ? Измените на 1) Либо уберите совсем

Comment: Сергей это сколько максимально дат может выбрать пользователь. Мне надо что бы пользователь мог выбирать несколько дат, а не одну.

Comment: Примером служила вот эта запись:
https://jsfiddle.net/Artemeey/3vuw12rj/14/